# Listbox Databinding Not working

Tags: c#, data-binding, listbox

I am unable figure out why the databinding is not working as expected:

- I created a Listbox and set its ItemSource to my observable collection
- I used this.DataContext = this
- I Initialized my public Observable Collection
- I filled it with objects that implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Yet, the databinding, still does not work. My Listbox:

```
<ListBox Height="425" ItemsSource="{Binding headers}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HeaderInfo}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class cornet_controls : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<headerInfo> headers;

    public cornet_controls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        headers = new ObservableCollection<headerInfo>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            headers.Add((new headerInfo() { HeaderInfo = x.ToString() }));            
    }        
}
```

My custom class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class headerInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public headerInfo()
    {}

    private String _HeaderInfo;

    public String HeaderInfo
    {
        get { return _HeaderInfo; }
        set { _HeaderInfo = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("HeaderInfo"); }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind to a NonProperty:

```
<ListBox Height="425" ItemsSource="{Binding headers}">

public ObservableCollection<headerInfo> headers;
```

you need to bind to a Property like:

```
public ObservableCollection<headerInfo> headers { get; set; }
```